# Is it possible to create an external stage against a blob storage table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to create an Snowflake external stage against an Azure blob storage table?  Or does it have to be a regular storage container that stores files?

If an external stage is not feasible here, what would be the best way to ingest data from a blob storage table?

Comment: The documentation states that blob storage is supported: "Use the blob.core.windows.net endpoint for all supported types of Azure blob storage accounts, including Data Lake Storage Gen2.". What type of data are you storing that you want to load into Snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it is not possible to use a blob storage table.  It must be a storage account that contains files.

SQL compilation error: Provided Azure storage endpoint 'mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net' is currently not supported.

If I use the endpoint 'mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net', it cannot find the storage table, it requires a container not a table.